# How to properly set lookup value in CRM 2011? I'm only getting halfway

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

After a lot of scouring for answers and experimenting I finally managed to put together something that doesn't end in complete fail. It can be seen below.

```
// set value in form field
function setLookup(lookupSchemaName, lookupGuid, lookupValue, lookupEntity)
{
    //var lookupSchemaName = 'uomid';
    //var lookupGuid   = '270BD3DB-D9AF-4782-9025-509E298DEC0A';
    //var lookupValue  = 'EACH';
    //var lookupEntity = 'unit';

    Xrm.Page.getAttribute(lookupSchemaName).setValue([{id: lookupGuid, name: lookupValue, entityType: lookupEntity}]);
}
```

This is attached to the onChange event of the product lookup field. It *works* but not completely. The problem is that when it runs I end up with a lookup field that contains the word 'EACH' and is highlighted in blue (indicative of a link being made with the record behind it; see image below) but is not fully accepted. It's a state of limbo so to speak.

What I expect to get is the entity's icon and a clickable value. I'm also unable to save the form but I can use the regular lookup function for the field and get things back to normal.

[image: Field state after value insertion]

Comment: The Unit of Measure entity is called 'uom'. Try setting the value using that. Your JS looks fine.

Comment: @glosrob It worked! Thank you thank you thank you. This brings up another quick question. What's the appropriate way to find the real entity name?

Comment: You can see it on the entity page. Settings -> Customisations -> Customise the System -> Entities. Select an entity. It's logical name is displayed under 'Name' (as opposed to the display/friendly name which is listed under 'Display Name')

Comment: Probably worth writing it up as answer so if anyone else comes across your question they will know the resolution (not everyone reads comments)

Comment: I will do that but I was assuming you would. Do you not want to officially take credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the display name for `Unit of Measure` and not the logical name.

The correct logical name for `Unit of Measure` is `uom`.

This can be found in CRM by going

`Settings > Customisations > Customise the System > Entities`

The logical name is displayed on the entity page.